# Error {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store} when testing IAP on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I struggled trying to find out why my previously-working in-app-purchase code was failing all of a sudden with

```
Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x8dcaae0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After hours of digging, I discovered that as of Xcode 5, In-App-Purchases in sandbox mode must be tested on an actual device, not via the simulator!

Comment: Not exactly. I'm having issues on my work iMac. It won't work in the simulator. But on my home MacbookPro, it does work in the simulator. I'm not sure how and it's driving me nuts that I can't use the simulator at work. Both machines have Maverick and XCode 5.0

Comment: Your are a lucky guy @HCHogan :). Because Apple blocked testing in-app purchase on the Simulator :  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241

Comment: I guess I was. What a fluke. For that past while, I've been testing on the devices as that seems to be what they want.

Answer (score 0):

It works on iOS8 simulator but not on iOS7.